# Golang weird change of value using Exp for big.Int inside a struct

Tags: go

In the below, `a` changes unexpectedly. `d` is constructed using the value of `a` (`*a`), then `d.c` is changed correctly. But why does `a` change to the 1st argument of `Exp`?

```
type Decimal struct {
    c big.Int // coefficient
    q big.Int // exponent
}
a := big.NewInt(1)
b := big.NewInt(2)
d := Decimal{*a, *b}
d.c.Exp(big.NewInt(11), big.NewInt(2), big.NewInt(0))
fmt.Println(a, b, d) // 11 2 {{false [121]} {false [2]}}
```

I was expecting `a` to remain unchanged.

EDIT: To add, I also printed the pointer addresses of `a`, `b`, `d.c`, `d.q` and all are different, both before and after `Exp`: `fmt.Printf("%p %p %p %p\n", &a, &b, &d.c, &d.q)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler example that shows the same thing:

```
x := big.NewInt(1)
y := *x
y.Exp(big.NewInt(11), big.NewInt(2), big.NewInt(0))
fmt.Println(x)  // 11
fmt.Println(&y) // 121
```

The first thing to consider is that [`y.Exp`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.Exp) "sets `z = x**y mod |m|` (i.e. the sign of `m` is ignored), and returns z."; so the value of `y` changes (as seen above).

To understand why that changes the value of `x` you can start with [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int):

> Operations always take pointer arguments (*Int) rather than Int values, and each unique Int value requires its own unique *Int pointer. To "copy" an Int value, an existing (or newly allocated) Int must be set to a new value using the Int.Set method; shallow copies of Ints are not supported and may lead to errors.

A "shallow copy" is exactly what the above `y := *x` (or the `d := Decimal{*a, *b}` in your code) is doing. So the solution is to follow the advice above:

```
x := big.NewInt(1)
y := new(big.Int).Set(x) // Avoid shallow copy
y.Exp(big.NewInt(11), big.NewInt(2), big.NewInt(0))
fmt.Println(x) // 1
fmt.Println(y) // 121
```

(you can do something similar in your example).

To explain why this happens you would need to look at how [`big.Int`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.3:src/math/big/int.go;l=33) is defined. This requires checking a few files but boils down (simplifying!) to:

```
type Int struct {
    neg bool // sign
    abs []uint // absolute value of the integer
}
```

So taking a shallow copy of this will lead to two instances with slices that share the same [backing array](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro) (which can lead to unpredictable results when elements in the slice are changed).

In your example the value changes when a [`set`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.3:src/math/big/nat.go;l=1005) is run. A simpler way to show this is:

```
x := big.NewInt(1)
y := *x
y.Set(big.NewInt(11))
fmt.Println(x)  // 11
fmt.Println(&y) // 11
```